# How can I add item to SharedPreferences with out coding in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I am new on flutter.
I'm using the SharedPreferences to keeping tokens and etc.

It works like below.

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String token = data['token'].toString();
prefs.setString("token", token);
```

Also, I would like to store my API user and API password in SharedPreferences. This information never gonna change.
But I don't want to add user/password information with prefs.setString("userkey", "uservalue");
I would like to add them with some kind of configuration or something like that. Not with the hard coding.

How can I do that?

Comment: 1- Don't do that. Sensible information should not be storage over SharedPreferences. 2- It's impossible to write a SharedPreference value without code.

Comment: so what do you suggest for storing ApiUser and Password? I will use them to get tokens from API.

Comment: don't store that. You can keep the token safely locally store with the flutter_secure_storage library and revoke tokens if there's any privacy issue/breach but they'll not have the full access to get new tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to store it in a file constants.dart

```
class Constants {
  static const String _kUser = " USERNAME";
  static const String _kKey = " APIKEY";
}
```